# Pareto optimality in Metropolis sampling

Tags: optimization, markov-chain-montecarlo, metropolis-hastings, random-walk

In the [Metropolis sampling algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metropolis%E2%80%93Hastings_algorithm), we have some function $f(x)$ proportional to a probability distribution $P(x)$.  To generate a random walk with stationary distribution $P(x)$, we generate a candidate $x'$ from a (symmetric) proposal distribution at previous step $x$ and keep it with probability $\min\left(\frac{f(x')}{f(x)},1\right)$.

Now, let's say we have multiple $f$'s, encoded as a function $F:x\mapsto \mathbb R^k$.  We again generate a proposal point $x'$, and we keep it with probability 
$$\min\left(1,\min_{\ell\in\{1,\ldots,k\}} \frac{F_\ell(x')}{F_\ell(x)}\right).$$
This random walk has two properties:  First, when $k=1$ this algorithm reduces to the Metropolis algorithm. Also, it keeps $x'$ any time $x'$ [Pareto dominates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_efficiency) $x$.

**Can we say anything about the stationary distribution of this walk?  Is it more likely to find points in the Pareto set of $F$?**

I'm also OK with asking the same question about any random walk with a similar Pareto property, if the particular acceptance probability above has some flaws.

Thanks!